# linux command ram type

Tags: linux, ram

I'm trying to determine the currently installed ram type of my linux machine by running the command 'dmidecode' but there must be an error because the ram type and other things are still unknown!?

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0019
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 2304 bits
    Data Width: 2244 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A0
    Bank Locator: Bank0/1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer:  
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag:  
    Part Number:
```

Is there another way to find out this stats?

Comment: Take a look on http://superuser.com/questions/377474/dmidecode-type-memory-showing-wrong-ddr-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in SUSE Linux lshw is not installed by default, but hwinfo is.

```
hwinfo --bios
```

gives me

```
[...]
Memory Device: #38
  Location: "DIMM1"
  Manufacturer: "Hyundai"
  Serial: "0F3005F1"
  Asset Tag: "000109"
  Part Number: "HMT125U6BFR8C-H9"
  Memory Array: #36
  Form Factor: 0x09 (DIMM)
  Type: 0x01 (Other)
  Type Detail: 0x0080 (Synchronous)
  Data Width: 64 bits
  Size: 2 GB
  Speed: 1333 MHz
Memory Device Mapping: #39
  Memory Device: #38
  Array Mapping: #37
  Row: 1
  Interleave Pos: 0
  Interleaved Depth: 1
  Start Address: 0x00000000
  End Address: 0x80000000
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `lshw`, it will give memory description and other system information.

Comment: lshw is a very thorough tool for finding out the details about all of your hardware, but it does cause some hardware to crash, so use it with caution.